# Application Defined or Object Defined Error in my code, no idea why

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to use `.formulaR1C1` to sum up values from different sheets on my main sheet for my workbook.
Everytime I run through my code it errors on the last bit where the formula is entered.

code:

```
For cRow = 9 To row
    For Each WS In Worksheets
        If Left(WS.Name, 5) <> "Total" Then
            If Left(WS.Name, InStr(WS.Name, " ") - 1) = "December" Then
                ytdSheet.Cells(cRow, 2).FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(" & ytdSheet.Cells(cRow, 2).Value & "'" & WS.Name & "'!RC)" 'HERE IS WHERE ERROR OCCURS!!!
            Else
                ytdSheet.Cells(cRow, 2).Value = ytdSheet.Cells(cRow, 2).Value & "'" & WS.Name & "'!RC,"
            End If
        End If
    Next WS
Next cRow
```

I feel like I am missing something simple, but I cannot figure it out.

Comment: Have you verified that `"=SUM(" & ytdSheet.Cells(cRow, 2).Value & "'" & WS.Name & "'!RC)"` always produces a valid formula?

Comment: `debug.print` of the line returns:
    `=SUM(January 2014'!RC,'February 2014'!RC,'March 2014'!RC,'April 2014'!RC,'May 2014'!RC,'June 2014'!RC,'July 2014'!RC,'August 2014'!RC,'September 2014'!RC,'October 2014'!RC,'November 2014'!RC,'December 2014'!RC)`

Comment: So if you paste that into a cell in your spreadsheet, does it evaluate without an error? Your formula seems to be missing a quote in front of January, so I would be surprised if it did.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I figured out why it wasn't working! my code was putting in a leading `'` but in the cell, it reads it as a "Make this a text entry" so it doesn't show up in the debug.print ..

I changed my code to use an array instead of the cell to hold the string while I build it, and then use the formulaR1C1 line to output to the cell..

```
For cRow = 9 To row
    For Each WS In Worksheets
        If Left(WS.Name, 5) <> "Total" Then
            If Left(WS.Name, InStr(WS.Name, " ") - 1) = "December" Then
                ytdSheet.Cells(cRow, 2).FormulaR1C1 = "=sum(" & sArr(1) & "'" & WS.Name & "'!R" & cRow & "C2)" 'HERE!!!
                'Debug.Print "=" & ytdSheet.Cells(cRow, 2).Value & "'" & WS.Name & "'!R" & cRow & "C2" 'HERE!!!
            Else
                sArr(1) = sArr(1) & "'" & WS.Name & "'!R" & cRow & "C2, "
                Debug.Print sArr(1)
            End If
        End If
    Next WS
Next cRow
```

works like a charm!